# Prove the homomorphism defined by $f∶S_n \rightarrow Sym(X), f(\sigma)=f\sigma,$ where $f\sigma(a_i)=\sigma \cdot a_i$ is injective.

Tags: group-theory

Let $X = {a_1,a_2,...,a_n}$ be a set with $n$ elements. Consider the action of $S_n$ on $X$ given by $\sigma \cdot a_i = a_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $\sigma \in S_n$ and for all $a_i \in X$.

I know to show an injective homomorphism we can use: $f(a)=e_H$ implies $a=e_G$ but of course in this case we would be using the identity function. However, I am unsure how this looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward symbolic manipulation to show $$\begin{align}
f(\sigma)=e\in\operatorname{Sym}X&\implies \sigma\cdot a_i=a_i\\
&\implies a_{\sigma(i)}=a_i\\
&\implies \sigma(i)=i,\forall i.
\end{align}$$

That is, $\sigma=e\in S_n$.

Comment: Thank you Chris!

Answer (score 2):

Consider more general case. You have a group $G$ acting on a set $X$. This induces a group homomorphism

$$F:G\to Sym(X)$$
$$F(g)=f_g$$

where $f_g:X\to X$ is the bijection given by $f_g(x)=gx$.

So what is the kernel of $F$? Assume that $F(g)=id$, i.e. $f_g(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$. This means that every element of $X$ is a fixed point of $g\in G$. So if the action of $G$ on $X$ is [faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions) then $g=e$ and so $F$ is injective.

It is not hard to see that $S_n$ acts faithfully on $X$ in your concrete case. Indeed, if $\sigma\in S_n$ is not the identity then by definition there is $a_i$ such that $\sigma\cdot a_i\neq a_i$. And so the action is faithful.

Comment: I haven't learned this terminology "faithful" yet. I've seen it but I don't know what it means.

Comment: @PhysicsBish It is not a difficult concept. It simply means that for any $g\in G$ there is $x\in X$ such that $gx\neq x$.